# ms access checking first column

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I'm having an issue with trying to figure out an employees first recruit using ms access.

My table is setup like so

```
|ID Number | Name | Start Date | Recruiter |
```

In the recruiter column it will be the ID Number

I know you can bring in a table twice in to access, but what i'm trying to figure out is how to find the First Recruit from the

Initially i brought in the table twice and inner joined the ID Number with the Recruiter column.

However this would display all the people recruited for each employee, and I only need to find the first Recruit.

Any thoughts?

Thanks

Comment: Can you edit your question to read clearer? Particularly "[...] how to find the First Recruit from the........" **the what?!**

Comment: So you want the MIN start_date, max(ID_NUMBER) GROUPED by Recruiter... as  a query, then join back to the base table to get the name...

Comment: Sorry to finish that sentance "I know you can bring in a table twice in to access, but what i'm trying to figure out is how to find the First Recruit from the same table"

Comment: @xQbert am i correct on joining the table twice?

Comment: @sao tith see answer below... sorry had to make a few corrections first...  should be correct now.  assuming a recruiter has only one recruit... otherwise multiple recruits on same day would be listed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of these problems as data sets.  You need a set of data which contains the recruiter, and the earliest date and some unique value of the original table (hoping these two things would be unique together)

Then join back to the base table... using the unique value as you have one set of data containing the records desired, and the base table contains the additional data desired.

Assuming that recruiter and the start date is unique... we can then join back to the base table to get the ID and name and id

This is a (SUB Select or inline view) to get the set of data for each recruiter and earliest recruit and id followed by a join back to the original table to get the name.

```
SELECT t1.[ID Number], t1.name, t1.[start date], t1.Recruiter
FROM Tablename t1
INNER JOIN (SELECT min(t3.[Start Date]) mSD, t3.Recruiter
FROM TableName t3
GROUP BY t3.Recruiter) t2
 on t1.[Start_date] = t2.mSD
and t1.recruiter = t2.recruiter
```

Comment: The FROM Tablename t1 is that referring to t1 ? or are we creating a new table? I'm  a little confused

Comment: table name needs to be substituted for the table you have.  t1, t2, and t3 are table aliases so the system doesn't get confused as to which table I was referring.  t2 is the name of the view the subselect generates.  t1 and t3 are in reference to the table name you have.  you'd have to alter that text. to your table... but that should be about it.  the subselect creates an in memory table called t2; using data from your table aliased as t3.  The in memory table is then joined back to your base table (t1) to limit the results to only display the recruiter's first hire.

Comment: Okay so if the table name is Employees, and i'm using the same table to inner join does this create an AS name for the table?

Comment: Remember i'm using the data only Individual table

Comment: i mean i'm only using one table

Comment: yes, table name needs to be changed to your tablename in both places.  on line 2 and 4 above before t1 and t3.  Its almost a self join, but not quite as we've limited the data in t2 inline view to be that of ONLY the earliest start date and the recruiter name.  This means we have the earliest date with recruiter name.